# SignalR sends only empty messages to client on testing server - However in localhost its working fine

Tags: signalr

I have website which implements signalR. All works well in localhost.

But on testing server I can see it connects & server sent events but all messages are empty.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Attached 2 images from diff. environments.

[image]

[image]

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: no error in console, but what I have noticed is it works sometimes when I refresh the page which is very weird.